# CouchDB proxy? Apache As a Reverse Proxy?

Tags: apache, apache2, couchdb

I have VM (Ubuntu 10.04, Apache, CouchDB 1.0, ...) with public ip address.

- Is it possible to **access CouchDB (mainly Futon) from public ip address** (i.e. 187.323.132.232:5984), not from http://localhost:5984?
- Or on my local machine, **set up an ssh tunnel**?

Answer (score 2):

- Yes, go to the Futon *Configuration* and set `bind_address` in the `http` section to `0.0.0.0`

  - Alternatively, you can use SSH also. The basic idea is to forward from your local machine to the remote CouchDB:

    ssh -L 5984:localhost:5984 remoteuser@remotemachine

  Now you can access Futon via http://localhost:5984/ from the local machine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can also proxy via Apache:

```
    ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:5984/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5984/
```

You should also be able to do this with the `[P]` flag on a RewriteRule, presuming mod_proxy has been enabled.

Comment: In which file do I have to setup this config?

Comment: @Jaseem Setup the configuration in a new config file in this directory /etc/apache2/sites-available/. I wrote a guide on how to configure Apache2 as reverse proxy for a Tomcat 7 server. Since it is HTTP forwards it will work exactly the same with CouchDB or any other HTTP server. http://macgyverdev.blogspot.se/2014/02/apache-web-server-as-reverse-proxy-and.html