# Explain CouchDB's serving of websites, is CouchDB bundled somehow with Apache and how does it work?

Tags: apache, authentication, couchdb, oauth-2.0, mod-proxy

I am trying to understand how CouchDB work. Does it come bundled up with separate Apache or does it use the Apache in the system. I am trying to understand how it determines where to serve the site and how are different directions done. This is important information because I am trying to understand how to implement the Apache 2.2 mod-proxy -module [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) with it. Do I need to tune CouchDB or do I need to tune a separate Apache process? Suppose you have 10 CouchDB processes and you want to direct their results to siteA, how can you do that?

Sorry I am now vague but I am trying to understand how to combine different things from one Site to another, having different authorization-cookies etc. I am having a problem where I have two separates sites `hello.com/myCouchDb/` and `hallo.de/someOthersite.html` working separately. When I merge the codes, the authentication fails -- I think there are at least three different solution candidates:

> **A)** redirect the verification things from the other site to another (a bit hackish) and/or
>
> **B)** somehow configure the CouchDB Apache -settings, I have tried in Futon but failed.
>
> **C)** store the authentication cookies to some dir or db and refresh them when they become old (or use never-old cookies)

So how can I merge different CouchDB -instances together with different authentication settings? Suppose you have ten people with different authentication cookies and you want to get them somehow incorporated to the same site. How can you do it? Do you tune network -settings, Apache -settings or CouchDB -settings? Or do you just stores the cookies to some directory or DB that you refresh every time they become old?

*P.s. I am the admin so do not worry about the OAuth2.0, I have the authentication-cookies to do whatever I want with the different instances. I just cannot understand how to merge the different instances.*

**Perhaps related**

> 2. [CouchDB proxy? Apache As a Reverse Proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398306/couchdb-proxy-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy)
> 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398389/different-definitions-of-the-term-proxy
> 4. [What is a proxy? What is it in Apache? Does it have many different meanings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397349/what-is-a-proxy-what-is-it-in-apache-does-it-have-many-different-meanings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're confused about the structure of CouchDB. CouchDB is a native JSON Database that has an HTTP API. That API is provided via Mochiweb, an Erlang based webserver that is bundled inside CouchDB. There's only one CouchDB server running, but it runs inside the Erlang Virtual Machine (BEAM) and has a fundamentally different architecture to the typical Apache httpd approach.

Regarding authentication, CouchDB has a per-instance (server) _users database that contains passwords and minimal account details. As an admin you can see this using Futon, although normal users only have access to their own profile. You can assign users into various roles, and then apply those roles and users to each database. Once the _security object is set on a DB, you need to be authenticated to read, and you can use validation update functions to enforce constraints on write. Some brief information on http://blog.couchbase.com/what%E2%80%99s-new-couchdb-10-%E2%80%94-part-4-security%E2%80%99n-stuff-users-authentication-authorisation-and-permissions and http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2012/03/definitive-guide-to-couchdb.html as well as on the wiki.

Comment: So this `"CouchDB -- has an HTTP API. That API is provided via Mochiweb, an Erlang based webserver that is bundled inside CouchDB."` means no Apache -server or what is that Mochiweb? Based on Apache or why under Apache-hosting? What is mod-proxy in Mochiweb? Suppose sites A and B have cookies and other relevant material -- and they should be hosted in site C. How? Second, I have to google/investigate a bit, anyway thank you for U -turning me +1

Comment: Apache Software Foundation is an volunteer-based organisation that writes and distributes awesome software. One of our projects is the Apache HTTPD server. And also CouchDB. There's no HTTPD components in CouchDB, we share only the organisation name - the brand, if you will. CouchDB doesn't need a proxy, and with CORS support coming in 1.3.0 you should be able to access your data almost anywhere on the web.